# why my Xcode doesn't find the .txt files that I create?

Tags: c, xcode

my program seems to "see" only the .txt files which he creates with the fopen("file.txt","w") function. I changed the working directory and put added the file to the project, but if I create the file.txt the program can't see it. the only way is to edit the one he creates with the open function

Answer (score 0):

You just have a problem concerning the *current directory*, it is not what you expect.

When you create "file.txt" it is created in the current directory because the path is not specified, so you can open it after because it is where the program look at by default.

{edit add}

You are under MacOS probably, if you start the program by hand from a shell like */Applications/......./prog* the current directory is the current directory where you are in the shell, but if you start it through its icon etc it will depends on the installation directory

Comment: sorry I don't understand... what should I do to solve my problem? anyway, yes, I'm under MacOs

Comment: @Valerio I don't know you context, your program can receive in parameter the pathname(s) of the file(s) or ask through a file explorer or any other ways where there are etc, rather than to suppose there are in the 'current directory'